# Display sum of quantity based product_id in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am creating ecommerce website in which we get record of how many product are orders for this purpose , i am creating orders table in which product_id and quantity are save. We need sum of quantity of each product. I want query that display expected result I tried lot but can not expected result.

Order Table:
    id          order_details
    1           Details of first order
    2           Details of second order
    3           Details of third order
    4           Details of fourth order
Sub Order Table
    id     order_id product_id   quantity
    1      1        1            2
    2      1        1            2
    3      1        2            2
    4      1        2            3
    5      1        2            3

expected output :

```
product_id  sum_orders_qty
1               4
2               8
```

Comment: Your expected output looks confusing.. May This helps you .https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-sum-a-comma-separated-string-string-with-numbers-in-mysql

Comment: @PunitGajjar yes i am editing

Comment: @PunitGajjar how can i create query?

Comment: I would suggest not to store the comma-separated values for product and quantity...